# fabric.js - fontsize limit

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I have an issue with fabric.js (1.4.0) and the fontsize when using the dataToURL function in high res for printing.

When Im scaling the text to big on the canvas and the dataToURL has a multiplier to scale the result up for 300dpi, the text is going wrong in the result. The result is send by ajax to a php script to render the image on the server. The canvas is 430x430px and the printimage is like 4700px.

If the fontsize is big enough the text wont get bigger in the result, only the spacing between the letter is growing. If the font-size isn't that big the result is correct.

I made a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/403e18m8/1/

```
$('#save').on('click', function() {
    var multiplier = 10;

    canvas.deactivateAll(); 
    canvas.setBackgroundColor('#FFFFFF');

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'jpg',
        multiplier: multiplier
    });
    window.open(dataURL);
});

canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

canvas.setWidth(430);
canvas.setHeight(430);

var textObject = new fabric.Text('123', {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    textAlign: 'left',
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    fontSize: 60,
    scaleX: 4,
    scaleY: 4
});

canvas.add(textObject);
canvas.renderAll();
```

The created image after using the save-button is not correct. If I'm changing the scaleX/Y to 1 or 2 it's fine.

Any idea how to avoid this?
Or maybe how to get the max supported fontsize and disallow to make it to big?

Comment: Also tested with the latest version 1.4.13 from github

Comment: Looks like the limit is only in Firefox (34). Chrome (35) has no limit or a much higher limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems to be a Firefox-limitation I'm observing the scaling event and stop at the maximum defined scale.